# sharepoint 2010 GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl not working

Tags: api, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

version: Sharepoint 2010
Hosted by Apps4rent
with sharepoint 2013 i was able to get folders and files using _api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('') API call
But with sharepoint 2010 instance if i try _api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('') this API it gives 404 error.
Please correct me if i am doing wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. SharePoint 2010 does not support `REST API` but you can use `listdata.svc` service.

Refer below code. This should work for you:

'https://abc.abcd.com/sites/RohitW/_vti_bin/Listdata.svc/DocLibTest2?$filter=endswith(Path, 'folder1')'

Note:
Here we are trying to get the files present inside the specific folder(i.e. folder1) of document library(i.e. DocLibTest2)

1. `DocLibTest2` is name of document library.
2. `folder1` is name of folder present inside `DocLibTest2`

Reference : http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2012/08/enumerating-items-inside-folder-using.html

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 not supported to use Rest API in browser directly,please use JSOM to call it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getFilesInFolder, 'sp.js');
    var files;
    function getFilesInFolder() {        
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();
        var folder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/test/Shared%20Documents');
        files = folder.get_files();
        context.load(files);
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnFailure));
    }
    function OnSuccess()
    {                                              
        var listItemEnumerator = files.getEnumerator();
            while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var fileUrl = listItemEnumerator.get_current().get_serverRelativeUrl();
                console.log(fileUrl);           
            }                                         
    }

    function OnFailure(sender, args) {
        alert("Failed. Message:" + args.get_message());
    }
</script>
```